# Recursive seek throught python dictionary to create Graphviz

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I've got dictionary with such body:

```
[
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "label": "Something20",
                                "id": 11
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "Something19",
                                "id": 12
                            }
                        ],
                        "label": "Something18",
                        "id": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "label": "Something15",
                                "id": 13
                            }
                        ],
                        "label": "Something14",
                        "id": 6
                    }
                ],
                "label": "Something2",
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "label": "Something10",
                                "id": 14
                            }
                        ],
                        "label": "Something9",
                        "id": 7
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Something8",
                        "id": 8
                    }
                ],
                "label": "Somethin7",
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "label": "Something5",
                        "id": 9
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Something4",
                        "id": 10
                    }
                ],
                "label": "Something2",
                "id": 4
            }
        ],
        "label": "Something1",
        "id": 1
    }
]
```

How can I recursively seek through this dict to generate Graphviz data like this:

```
Something1->Something2
Something1->Something7
```

So e.g. list called `edges = []` and append to it some data as touples (only labels):

```
[("Something1", "Something2"), ("Something1", "Something7")]
```

After data is generated I can then simply generate object in Graphviz (Generate PNG Image) representing tree structure of provided dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this recursively, you can have a function, that generates an edge from the node it is passed to each of its children, as well as calling itself for each of the children. Then all you need to do is call it for every node in the root list (and you need to collect all generated edges in a list). This could be implemented as follows (`root` holds your data):

```py
def get_edges(node):
    if "children" not in node: # ensure the node has children
        return []
    label = node["label"]
    children = node["children"]
    result = [(label, c["label"]) for c in children] # create the edges
    for c in children:
        result.extend(get_edges(c)) # travers the tree recursively and collect all edges
    return result

edges = sum(map(get_edges, root), []) # create and combine all the edge lists
```

Running this code with the data you provided yields the following:

```
[('Something1', 'Something2'), ('Something1', 'Somethin7'), 
 ('Something1', 'Something2'), ('Something2', 'Something18'), 
 ('Something2', 'Something14'), ('Something18', 'Something20'), 
 ('Something18', 'Something19'), ('Something14', 'Something15'), 
 ('Somethin7', 'Something9'), ('Somethin7', 'Something8'), 
 ('Something9', 'Something10'), ('Something2', 'Something5'), 
 ('Something2', 'Something4')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns __TypeError: string indices must be integers__

Comment: I think it is happening because not always node containt 'children' key.

Comment: I have added a check, to ensure the node has children. But that solves a different problem the code had (if a node does not have children, python will give you a `KeyError: 'children'`, not the `TypeError` you described). I would guess that there is a node in your data, which has a child which is only a string, not a dictionary. I have tested the code with the data you provided and added the results to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured out similar thing:  *if not children: return [ ]* .